# How do I get back into Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I'm not sure where to begin.  I was using 17.04, everything was working great and after an update yesterday morning, GNOME started to act funky (i.e. couldn't open any programs, even the command-line).  I rebooted, as that usually solves the problem, and that's when I realized I had a big problem.  Without going into great detail of what I was seeing, let's just say there were errors and all I can get to is the terminal login.  I have tirelessly read forums and tried to figure out why GNOME won't load but still can't figure it out.  In desperation, I upgraded to 18.04 today hoping that would solve the problem... nope.  To make matters worse, I get errors when trying to apt-get update.

I can get into all my files and folders but not sure what adjustments need to be made to get me back up and running.  If there's anyone out there that has some troubleshooting ideas I would be very grateful.

Thanks community!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could further describe the errors you see in order to find a solution. Maybe the errors are in `/var/log/syslog`.  Since you can use the terminal, one solution might be to re-install gnome by `sudo apt-get purge gnome && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get install gnome`, but without knowing the concrete problem, this is only a wild guess (and it will only work if the network is working).

Comment: We cannot help you much without that "great deal of detail of what I was seeing". That's really most of what we need to help you.